# Querying dynamo db if key exists in java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am new to dynamo db. Given this filter condition on aws UI

```
student_name - exists
```

I could filter the rows only if student_name key exists. How do I query the same in java. I am using the following code

```
 QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
         .withKeyConditionExpression("Exists('student_name'')");
 ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> allRows = myTable.scan(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use QuerySpec Java class to achieve similar results.

[Javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/spec/QuerySpec.html)

[Reference and code example:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html)